# No-arg constructor missing, but should be present

Tags: spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea, kotlin, compilation

In my Spring Boot app I have an entity class without no-arg constructor, but with fields initialzed.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
data class User(
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        var id: Long? = null,
        @Column(name = "username", unique = true, nullable = false)
        var username: String = "",
        @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
        var password: String = "",
        @Column(name = "language")
        var language: String? = null,
        @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)], inverseJoinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)])
        var roles: Set<Role> = HashSet(),
        @OneToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "active_profile")
        var activeProfile: ExchangeProfile? = null
)
```

Then I have a generic method which creates instances of these classes:

```
private fun createNewInstance(): T = itemClass.createInstance()
```

As I have read compiler should generate no-arg constructor and there should be no problem in this code.
Running this code in IntelliJ Idea using "Run configuration" button works without problem.

But running it from console using

```
mvn clean compile spring-boot:run
```

(or in docker) throws an exception:

```
Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class should have a single no-arg constructor: class com.iwaneez.stuffer.core.persistence.entity.User
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:213) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:117) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:308) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        ... 75 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class should have a single no-arg constructor: class com.iwaneez.stuffer.core.persistence.entity.User
        at kotlin.reflect.full.KClasses.createInstance(KClasses.kt:281) ~[kotlin-reflect-1.3.61.jar:1.3.61-release-180 (1.3.61)]
        at com.iwaneez.stuffer.core.ui.component.masterdetail.DetailComponent.createNewInstance(DetailComponent.kt:104) ~[classes/:na]
```

Do you have any ideas, how to fix it without explicitly define no-arg constructor?

Comment: Does this happen if your class `User` is `public`?

Comment: It looks like something that shouldn't happen. You can try to decompile this class to check which argument Kotlin cannot move to default constructor or something like that.  
And also you can try to add `@JvmOverloads` to constructor.

Comment: nothing of this makes any change. I have tried to decompile to java and the no arg constructor is present, but with additional two params:


`public User() {
      this((Long)null, (String)null, (String)null, (String)null, (Set)null, (ExchangeProfile)null, 63, (DefaultConstructorMarker)null);
   }`